# Obtain Update Table Lock at start of Stored Procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, locking

I'm writing a SQL Server stored procedure in which I want to lock a table for update before executing the body of the stored procedure.  I don't want to prevent other processes from reading the table, but I do want to prevent other processes updating the table.

Here is my first attempt:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE someProcedure
BEGIN
   SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMITTED
   BEGIN TRANSANCTION
     SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TheTable WITH (UPDLOCK, TABLOCK)

     -- Pause procedure so that we can view the locks with sp_lock
     WAITFOR DELAY '00:15'

     -- Do stuff
   COMMIT
END
```

When I execute the stored procedure, and invoke sp_lock, I see that the table is indeed locked. However, it's locked with an Exclusive lock instead of an update lock:

```
spid | dbid | ObjId     | IndId | Type | Resource | Mode | Status
------------------------------------------------------------------
63   | 10   | 233208031 | 0     | TAB  |          | X    | GRANT
```

How can I get an update (U) lock instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said:

> I don't want to prevent other
>   processes from reading the table, but
>   I do want to prevent other processes
>   updating the table.

You simply need a shared read lock for the duration of the TXN. This means no other process can get a "write" lock, in conjunction with a TABLOCK. And you don't need COUNT either.

```
...
   BEGIN TRANSANCTION
     SELECT TOP 1 KeyCol FROM TheTable WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
...
```

Why do you think you want an UPDATE LOCK?

[HOLDLOCK or SERIALIZABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)

> Is equivalent to SERIALIZABLE. For more
>   information, see SERIALIZABLE later in
>   this topic. HOLDLOCK applies only to
>   the table or view for which it is
>   specified and only for the duration of
>   the transaction defined by the
>   statement that it is used in.
>   ...
>   Makes shared locks more restrictive by
>   holding them until a transaction is
>   completed, instead of releasing the
>   shared lock as soon as the required
>   table or data page is no longer
>   needed, whether the transaction has
>   been completed or not.

**Edit, after comment:**

- "exclusive lock" means "only one process using the data".
- "SERIALIZABLE" basically means hold the locks (shared, exclusive, whatever) for a lot longer.

You can't specify "exclusive lock" *and* allow other processes to read. The concepts are mutually exclusive. You want to prevent writes to the entire table, which a *persisted* shared/read lock will do. This is where SERIALIZABLE comes in.

From ["Lock Modes"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519.aspx)

> Shared Locks
>
> ...No other
>   transactions can modify the data while
>   shared (S) locks exist on the
>   resource. Shared (S) locks on a
>   resource are released as soon as the
>   read operation completes, unless the
>   transaction isolation level is set to
>   repeatable read or higher, or a
>   locking hint is used to retain the
>   shared (S) locks for the duration of
>   the transaction.

**So: a shared lock disallows writes and can be made to persist by making it SERIALIZABLE**

Comment: Does this effectively get an exclusive lock? My understanding of SERIALIZABLE is that (semantically) only one process can read/update the table at any given time. The table in question is read from much more often than it is written to. We have a maintenance task that needs to perform some periodic clean up of the table. While the clean up is running, we don't want to prevent the majority of processes from reading the table, however, we do want to prevent concurrent updates (which could potentially invalidate the cleanup). In this case, dirty reads and non-repeatable reads are okay.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that a shared lock disallowed writes.

Answer (score 1):

**TABLOCK**

Specifies that a lock is taken on the table and held until the end-of-statement. If data is being read, a shared lock is taken. If data is being modified, an exclusive lock is taken. If HOLDLOCK is also specified, a shared table lock is held until the end of the transaction.

When used with the OPENROWSET bulk rowset provider to import data into a table without indexes, TABLOCK enables multiple clients to concurrently load data into the target table with optimized logging and locking.

Taken from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: @Jim Hurne: Have you tried the UPDLOCK on it's own without the TABLOCK?

Comment: Yes. it puts an update lock on all of the rows in the table, but I don't think it will prevent new rows from being added (as the lock itself is not applied to the table).  I'm trying to decide if this is okay for the application I'm working on. Maybe SQL Server only uses update locks for rows and not tables?