# TSQL implementing double check locking

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, concurrency, locking

I have an arbitrary stored procedure `usp_DoubleCheckLockInsert` that does an `INSERT` for multiple clients and I want to give the stored procedure exclusive access to writing to a table `SomeTable` when it is within the critical section `Begin lock` and `End lock`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_DoubleCheckLockInsert
     @Id INT
    ,@SomeValue INT
AS
BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SomeTable WHERE Id = @Id AND SomeValue = @SomeValue)) RETURN
    BEGIN TRAN
        --Begin lock
        IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SomeTable WHERE Id = @Id AND SomeValue = @SomeValue)) ROLLBACK

        INSERT INTO SomeTable(Id, SomeValue)
        VALUES(@Id,@SomeValue);
        --End lock
    COMMIT
END
```

I have seen how Isolation Level relates to updates, but is there a way to implement locking in the critical section, give the transaction the writing lock, or does TSQL not work this way?

[Obtain Update Table Lock at start of Stored Procedure in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973447/obtain-update-table-lock-at-start-of-stored-procedure-in-sql-server)

Comment: Why not just create a unique constraint on `Id, SomeValue`? See [Only inserting a row if it's not already there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3407857/73226)

Comment: That is a way to fix the problem at the data level, but in my case some records have a soft delete flag called `IsDelete`, so multiple records of the same `Id` and `SomeValue` are allowed.

Comment: You can use a unique filtered index to enforce this. `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX ON SomeTable(Id,SomeValue) WHERE IsDelete = 0`

Comment: Is this really preferable over double check locking? This will cause an error on insert versus simply returning to the caller which means I'll need a `BEGIN TRY` block and all the associated `BEGIN CATCH` cruft.

Comment: If this is the only way users can access this table you might want to look into sp_getapplock http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx

Comment: @MartinSmith I think a unique index is good to ensure duplicates do not get inserted into the table, but I would rather be proactive than reactive when possible.

Comment: "Is this really preferable over double check locking?" - yes, yes it is. After all the contortions you'll go through, SQL Server will still apply all of *its* normal locking mechanisms. In this case, catching the error *is* the preferred way to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A second approach which works for me is to combine the `INSERT` and the `SELECT` into a single operation.

This index needed only for efficiently querying `SomeTable`.  Note that there is NOT a uniqueness constraint. However, if I were taking this approach, I would actually make the index unique.

```
CREATE INDEX [IX_SomeTable_Id_SomeValue_IsDelete] ON [dbo].[SomeTable]
(
    [Id] ASC,
    [SomeValue] ASC,
    [IsDelete] ASC
)
```

The stored proc, which combines the INSERT/ SELECT operations:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_DoubleCheckLockInsert]
     @Id INT
    ,@SomeValue INT
    ,@IsDelete bit
AS
BEGIN
```

<strike>`-- Don't allow dirty reads`</strike>

<strike>`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED`</strike>

```
    BEGIN TRAN
        -- insert only if data not existing
        INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable(Id, SomeValue, IsDelete)
        SELECT @Id, @SomeValue, @IsDelete
        where not exists (
            select * from dbo.SomeTable WITH (HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK)
            where Id = @Id
            and SomeValue = @SomeValue
            and IsDelete = @IsDelete)

    COMMIT
END
```

I did try this approach using multiple processes to insert data. (I admit though that I didn't exactly put a lot of stress on SQL Server).  There were never any duplicates or failed inserts.

Comment: Both of your answers are correct. I will accept the one you feel better follows SQL conventions.

Comment: @Romoku - to me they would both be equally fine. Maybe you should wait a bit and see which gets more votes. Of course for this answer, I would create a unique index (as I suggest above in the answer itself).

Comment: @Romoku - upon further testing I found that my original SQL would occasionally fail because it tried to insert a record that was already there. The fix for this is to add the table hints (`holdlock`, `updlock`) in the sub-select. The `holdlock` is equivalent to `serializable`, which single threads all access. Also, according to MSDN if there are table hints, then any `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` statements are ignored for those tables. I have updated my answer to reflect my findings.

Answer (score 1):

It seems all you are trying to do is to prevent duplicate rows from being inserted.  You can do this by adding a unique index, with the option `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_SomeTable_Id_SomeValue_IsDelete]
ON [dbo].[SomeTable]
(
    [Id] ASC,
    [SomeValue] ASC,
    [IsDelete] ASC
) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
```

Any inserts with duplicate keys will be ignored by SQL Server. Running the following:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SomeTable] ([Id],[SomeValue],[IsDelete])
VALUES(0,0,0)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[SomeTable] ([Id],[SomeValue],[IsDelete])
VALUES(1,1,0)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[SomeTable] ([Id],[SomeValue],[IsDelete])
VALUES(2,2,0)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[SomeTable] ([Id],[SomeValue],[IsDelete])
VALUES(0,0,0)
```

Results in:

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

Duplicate key was ignored.
(0 row(s) affected)
```

I did not test the above using multiple processes (threads), but the results in that case should be the same - SQL Server should still ignore any duplicates, no matter which thread is attempting the insert.

See also [Index Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186869.aspx) at MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may not understand the question but why couldn't you do this:

```
begin tran
if ( not exists ( select 1 from SomeTable where Id = @ID and SomeValue = @SomeValue ) )
    insert into SomeTable ( Id, SomeValue ) values ( @ID, @SomeValue )
commit
```

Yes you have a transaction every time you do this but as long as your are fast that shouldn't be a problem.

I have a feeling I'm not understanding the question.

Jeff.

Comment: But if you are running concurrently, shouldn't everybody else wait until you release the transaction with the commit?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you start messing with sql preferred locking management, you are taking the burdon on, but if you're certain this is what you need, update your sp to select a test variable and replace your "EXISTS" check with that variable.  When you query the variable use an exclusive table lock, and the table is yours till your done.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_DoubleCheckLockInsert
     @Id INT
    ,@SomeValue INT
AS
BEGIN
     IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SomeTable WHERE Id = @Id AND SomeValue = @SomeValue)) RETURN
     BEGIN TRAN
        --Begin lock
         DECLARE @tId as INT
         -- You already checked and the record doesn't exist, so lock the table
         SELECT @tId 
         FROM SomeTable WITH (TABLOCKX)
         WHERE Id = @Id AND SomeValue = @SomeValue
         IF @tID IS NULL
           BEGIN
             -- no one snuck in between first and second checks, so commit
           INSERT INTO SomeTable(Id, SomeValue)
           VALUES(@Id,@SomeValue);
        --End lock
     COMMIT
END
```

If you execute this as a query, but don't hit the commit, then try selecting from the table from a different context, you will sit and wait till the commit is enacted.

Answer (score 0):

Romoku, the answers you're getting are basically right, except

- that you *don't even need* `BEGIN TRAN`.
- you don't need to worry about isolation levels.

All you need is a simple `insert ... select ... where not exists (select ...)` as suggested by Jeff B and Chue X.

Your concerns about concurrency ("I'm talking about concurrency and your answer will not work.") reveal a profound misunderstanding of how SQL works.

SQL `INSERT` *is* atomic.  You don't have to lock the table; that's what the DBMS does for you.

Instead of offering a bounty for misbegotten questions based on erroneous preconceived notions -- and then summarily dismissing right answers as wrong -- I recommend sitting down with a good book.  On SQL.  I can suggest some titles if you like.

Comment: Jeff never suggested the `insert ... select ... where not exists (select ...)` which would work. You are correct that I did not realize `INSERT` is atomic, so combining the duplicate checking logic into the `INSERT` statement is the proactive approach I was seeking.