# Understanding the SQL Server deadlock diagram

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an application which will be chosen as the "deadlock victim" in SQL Server. There are multiple threads which try to execute below queries.

**Query**

```
merge Table_X as target  
using (values ('14410')) as source (CUST_ID) on target.CUST_ID = '14410'
when matched then  
    update 
       SET CUST_NAME = 'xyz', CLOSE_DATE = NULL,
           xx = 2, COMPLETE = 'No', 
           qwert = CASE  WHEN qwert is null and 'Low' = 'High' THEN getDate() ELSE null END, 
           ACTIVE = 1, xcount = '913af80db3f424e34a9055e0ea9bc391'  

when not matched then  
   INSERT (CUST_ID, CUST_NAME, OPEN_DATE, CLOSE_DATE, xx, COMPLETE, qwert, ddd, ACTIVE, xcount )  
   VALUES ('14410', 'U.S. Robotics and Mechanical Men', '2007-08-31 15:14:23.0', NULL, 2, 'No', NULL, 0, 1, '913af80db3f424e34a9055e0ea9bc391') ;

DECLARE @54229 numeric(19,0)
SET @54229 = ( SELECT id from Table_X  where CUST_ID = '14410' )

insert into Table_Y (xyz, abc, ax, ay, az, bx, bxz, bz, UPDATED, abcd) 
   select 
       xyz, abc, ax, ay, az, bx, bxz, bz, UPDATED, abcd 
   from 
       Table_Z 
   where 
       abcd = @54229

merge Table_Z as target 
using (values (@54229)) as source (abcd) on target.abcd = @54229 
when matched then  
    UPDATE  
       SET xyz = 1.1, abc = 1.1, ax = 1.1, ay = 1.1, az = 1.1, 
           bx = 1.1, bxz = 'Low', bz = 1.1, UPDATED = getdate()

when not matched then 
    INSERT (xyz, abc, ax, ay, az, IS_FORCE_EDD, bx, bxz, bz, UPDATED, abcd) 
    VALUES(1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 0, 1.1,'Low', 1.1, getdate(), @54229);

INSERT INTO Table_A(ACTION, DATE_TIME, PROFILE_ID, USER_ID)
VALUES('Profile Change', getdate(), @54229, 1)
```

[Deadlock diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCiSR.png)

Can anyone explain this deadlock diagram?

And provide me the solution to prevent this deadlock.

I have read multiple stuff and tried `with (nolock)`, `isolation level`, but I am not getting proper solution.

Is there any indexes related issue possible for a deadlock victim?

Comment: a deadlock message can also come up if it is just to slow to finish.  try improving the performance of your query.

Comment: @Hogan a deadlock error is only thrown if an actual deadlock is detected.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I don't believe it is possible to detect a deadlock -- I believe a heuristic is used and this heuristic can give a "false positive" in cases of one process locking a resources and being "slow" to free it.

Comment: @hogan well you believe wrong then. Google deadlock detection algorithms. The deadlock graph  will contain details of the circular wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created the non-clustered index
  and after that I haven't observed the deadlock victim exceptions.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [T_abcd] ON [dbo].[Table_Z]
    (
        [abcd] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I think getting a read lock on TABLE_Z early in your code will solve the problem.

Here's a question about that:
[Obtain Update Table Lock at start of Stored Procedure in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973447/obtain-update-table-lock-at-start-of-stored-procedure-in-sql-server).

Edit: You are reading from TABLE_Z before you are writing to it. Lets say you have two threads/connections (A & B) running:

A takes a read lock

B takes a read lock

A tries to take a write lock but has to wait for B to release the read lock.

B tries to take a write lock but has to wait for A to release the read lock.

Now there's a deadlock.

Comment: Can you explain it with example? and Is there any role of table indexes?